# How to modify external variable inside jq walk

Tags: bash, jq

I'm currently writing a script that uses the function `walk` in jq, which I'm using to check for the value of a field, which can appear multiple times in the file. If any instance of that field is not `true`, I want to echo an error notifying users that the field is invalid. Similar to below:

```
flag=false

cat file.json | jq 'walk (
  if type == "object" and has "foo" and (.foo != true); then
     flag=true
  else . end
)'

if [[ "$flag" == true ]]; then
  echo "ERROR"
  exit 1
fi
```

How can I notify the rest of the program if the check inside `walk` fails ? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Note that in the FP paradigm, you cannot just *change* a variable's value. You can only bind it for the given context. Moreover, jq's variables are not shell variables; you'd need to capture the result of the jq call from the shell to be able to process it's value there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't using [`all`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#all%2Call%28condition%29%2Call%28generator%3Bcondition%29) and the `--exit-status` (or `-e`) [option](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq) make more sense here?

```bash
if jq -e 'all(.. | objects | select(has("foo")); .foo)' file.json >/dev/null
then
  echo "All true"
else
  echo "At least one not true"
fi
```

Comment: I need to invalidate cases where `foo` is anything but the primitive `true`. With this approach, when I try `"foo": "bar"`, it also passes the conditional. Can you please suggest how I can achieve this ?

Comment: @lem Try changing `; .foo)` to `; .foo == true)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid entanglements with the shell, e.g. as follows:

```
jq 'if all(.. | objects | select(has("foo")); .foo) 
    then "All truthy" 
    else "At least one not truthy"
    end'
```